# URLSearchParams with axios instance in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I was attempting to send `payload`, and `URLSearchParams` through an `API` URL from my `react-native` application. I initialized an `axios` instance as,

```
import { BASE_URL } from '../../utils/constants';
const axios = require('axios');

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    timeout: REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
});
```

And from another component, I imported the `axios` instance, then,

```
 import api from "../../utils/api"
 import { API_URL } from '../../utils/constants';

 requestAPI(userId, sessionId){
    let data = { "userId": userId, "sessionId": sessionId };
    
    api
      .post(API_URL, data)
      .then(response => {
        // handle the response
        // do stuffs
   })
}
```

The `payload` contains the request body for the API. As stated in  API docs, I have to send the filters through `URLSearchParams`, like,

```
 api
   .post(API_URL?status=success&type=out, data)
   .then(response => .... {
       //handle the response and stuffs
   });
```

Any suggestions on how to send the `URLSearchParams` without hardcoding or just appending search queries to the `API_URL`? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `new URL()` and assign the URLSearchParams() to the `search` property of the URL object.

You can then pass that object directly to axios

```js
const API_URL ='https://httpbin.org/get',
      REQ_URL = new URL(API_URL);
      
const data = Object.entries({'foo':'bar', age:23}),      
      params = new URLSearchParams(data);
      
// to manually add params      
params.append('username', 'foobar');      
      
REQ_URL.search = params;


// example passing url object to fetch()
(async ()=>{
   console.log('REQ_URL :', REQ_URL)
   const req= await fetch(REQ_URL);
   const {args, url} = await req.json();
   console.log('URL from response:',url)
   console.log(args)
})()
```